# SEO impact of load Balancing using iFrames

Tags: seo, iframe, load-balance

When a user accesses my website, there is going to be an iFrame on a subdomain, on a different IP address. There are going to be multiple IP addresses for different subdomains, that essentially hold the same webpage. The URL of the iFrame page will be updated dynamically, depending on different webserver loads. The users will still be able to see the correct URL in browser, by messaging from iFrames, and updating URL via history API.

What are the disadvantages? Is there any way to tell search engines to crawl the iFrame? What is wrong with this idea?

Comment: The content in an iframe is not considered part of the parent page, SE bots will crawl the iframe content as if it were a separate website. It doesn't matter if it is a different IP address if it is the same webserver server. You are also not doing any sort of load balancing since the page that you are putting you iframes on will still be loaded for every page view regardless of which iframe you load. I suggest checking out a couple of the other questions relating to iframes and SEO.